# How do you restrict which branches can be pulled into a target branch

Tags: azure-devops, git-merge

I'm trying to set up policies on my Azure DevOps Branches.
I'm able to state that a branch must build and pass our unit tests before allowing a merge but is there a way to restrict which branch is allowed to merge into it.

I have two branches that this would impact.
I have my 'master' branch that I would like to restrict to only accept pull requests from a branch called 'UAT'.
I have a branch called 'UAT' that I would like to restrict to only accept pull requests coming from a branch called 'Dev'.

Comment: Do you use GitHub or Azure Repos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest workaround I could think of is to have a very simple pipeline that would run on pull requests and check `System.PullRequest.SourceBranch` and `System.PullRequest.TargetBranch`. If the values don't match your policy, then fail the pipeline, which in turn will block the PR.

Example code:

```
  - powershell: >
     if (("$(System.PullRequest.SourceBranch)" -ne "refs/heads/acc" -And "$(System.PullRequest.TargetBranch)" -eq "refs/heads/main")
     -Or ("$(System.PullRequest.SourceBranch)" -ne "refs/heads/test" -And "$(System.PullRequest.TargetBranch)" -eq "refs/heads/acc"))
     {
      Write-Error "
      =========================================================================================================
      Branch check failed.
      Illegal Pull Request from $(System.PullRequest.SourceBranch) into $(System.PullRequest.TargetBranch).
      ========================================================================================================="
     }
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'))
  displayName: Branch Check
```

Comment: Found this post after wrongfully PRed the test branch into main and thus deployed the new structure to production. This 'workaround'  sounds good. I will try to implement this. Will let you know what I found.

Comment: I edited the answer above with the code I implemented to block illegal pull requests.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer by qbik i created this short yaml code. Replace the source and target as needed for your use case. The code below is only for testing in my pipeline, to create the desired failure.

```
- powershell: >
     if ("$(System.PullRequest.SourceBranch)" -ne "refs/heads/acc" -And "$(System.PullRequest.TargetBranch)" -eq "refs/heads/test")
     {
      Write-Error "
      =========================================================================================================
      Branch check failed.
      Illegal Pull Request from $(System.PullRequest.SourceBranch) into $(System.PullRequest.TargetBranch).
      ========================================================================================================="
     }
  displayName: Branch Check
```